# How to load data from XML file into HTML5

Tags: xml, html

I know it's a simple question but i just can't find the right answer!

I need a simple way/code , function, parser i dunno ! i just want a way to load data from my XML file into HTML5.

I need my web app to load the data from that XML file and show them !

Comment: You need to give more information -- what kind of coding language are you using, how are you trying to show the data, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

First: Pick a programming language. Your decision will be informed by a combination of what languages you know/like/want-to-learn and what your server supports (you might also choose client side JavaScript). You may choose to change hosting package / company to get support for the language of your choice.

Second: Pick an XML library for that language.

Third: Pick a template library for that language.

Fourth: Write glue code to parse the XML and output HTML. Use a validator to check conformance to the HTML 5 specification.

Comment: i already have an XML file written and done,
I want to Write using JAvascript or php or whatever a function or a method to access the xml file and show his values,
i was used to doing it using Action Script and i am very new to HTML5

Comment: So start by choosing "JavaScript or PHP or whatever".

Answer (score 0):

To add to previous answers, there are many ways to integrate XML data into your webpages. One method would be to use JavaScript - a client-side solution, maybe one that uses the popular framework, JQuery. There are numerous other methods and frameworks, as well as server side processing languages, like PHP and .NET.

Answer (score -1):

Why make things complicated when they can be simple?

Use half a dozen lines of code and XMLHttpRequest() javascript function.

Comment: This answer is too vague. At least show some code if it's only a dozen lines, as your response isn't helpful.